# Open Graph can't play GIF from my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, animated-gif

I can't undrestand why Facebook can't play all GIFs from my website? For example when I debug this page, Facebook don't show the GIF:
https://keepgif.com/gif/when-your-dad-live.html
The file is not too big and his width is greater than 200px. So where is the problem please? Is there some recomandations that I have to know to force Open Graphe to play any GIF from my website?

Comment: `og:url` should point to the HTML document, not directly to an image.

Comment: In this case facebook will generate a preview of my page while I need to play a GIF from my website to facebook.

Take this site as an example:
[View-source:http://gifspace.net/image/ztYp]
`<meta property="og:url" content="http://gifspace.net/image/ztYp.gif"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="Good goalkeeping"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://gifspace.net/image/ztYp.gif"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="GIFspace"/>`
In og:url they put the link of the GIF and it works. Why when I do the same thing it does not work in 100% in case?

Comment: _“In this case facebook will generate a preview of my page”_ - yes, and the image you specified is used as the thumbnail.

Comment: Yes but i don't need image to be as a thumbnail. I want to play this image(GIF). take a look at this example:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Ffunny-gifs.me%2Fimg.php%3Fid%3D9100

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am having the same issue. Sometimes, with the exact same settings, the gif will animated. Other times it will not.

Comment: @CBroe I have similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72976121/why-facebook-does-not-animate-gif-if-gif-is-used-as-ogimg

Answer (score 0):

href from `<meta property="og:image" content="https://keepgif.com/embed/w47u5Kdx.gif">`

`https://keepgif.com/embed/w47u5Kdx.gif`

redirect to your site. I guess, this may be problem.