# Why Facebook does not animate gif, if gif is used as og:img?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, gif, meta-tags, facebook-sharer, share-open-graph

I have this post: https://tikex-dev.com/kubl/szkg/j1vd/7w68
it has og:img: https://t44-post-cover.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/v56o

If you load it in a browser it animates, but not on Facebook, why?

And I have those headers:

```html
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta property="og:title" content="555">
<meta property="og:description" content="555">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://t44-post-cover.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/v56o">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1920">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="1080">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/gif">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="402670860613108">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://tikex-dev.com/kubl/szkg/j1vd/7w68">
<meta name="next-head-count" content="11">
</head>
```

Giphy uses mp4 as og:video. Do I really need video to show an animation?
Tenor uses webm format in og:video.  Is og:video really needed?

Comment: _"If you load it in a browser it animates, but not on Facebook, why?"_ - because Facebook doesn't show animations in link preview thumbnails, but only static images? I have never seen any post that had an animated image as thumbnail for an external link.

Comment: What about this here? I need to use mp4 at og:video then? https://giphy.com/gifs/transparent-I49AqHuI8NdmgL5NAc or can I use gif but as og:video?

Comment: Facebook hasn't displayed `og:video` as a playable video in newsfeed for years.

Comment: try to share this link from Giphy site with share button, or just put this link into you Facebook, it is an animation: https://giphy.com/gifs/transparent-I49AqHuI8NdmgL5NAc

Comment: or check here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgiphy.com%2Fgifs%2Ftransparent-I49AqHuI8NdmgL5NAc it has an animated link preview, or is Giphy special or Tenor?

Comment: But that is not actually sharing a link, it shares the GIF only.

Comment: Ok, but this here is the sharing link: https://giphy.com/stickers/transparent-I49AqHuI8NdmgL5NAc and it renders in Facebook also an animation

Comment: I can share that so that it shows the actual URL as part of the message, but that is a different thing than an actual link post. And it looks like Giphy is achieving this by specifying the URL of the actual GIF as `og:url`.

Comment: I see, do you know maybe why og:url is not taken from mata tag? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72979453/why-ogurl-is-not-taken-from-meta-tags